# Is $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 1/(x-4)$ a function?

Tags: functions

Just a quick question.

Is "$f : \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = 1/(x−4)$" a function?
I'm thinking it can't be because if $x$ is $4$ then it would give the answer infinity?

Comment: You would be correct in that it is not defined at $x=4$. You could argue $\pm \infty$, but then you would need the codomain to be the extended reals.

Comment: This is  a function according to the definition(s) presented in:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics). It is not continuous at x=4, hence it may be considered as a "partial function" - See more at:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function

Comment: It's simply not defined at $x =4$, *as a real-valued function*, so No, it is not a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$, but it is a function with domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{4\}$. In some subjects "partial functions" are objects of interest, and this would be one. But unless your book/course/teacher has used that phrase, forget you heard it: the question being asked is, Is this $f$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$? and the expected answer is No.

Answer (score 1):

This function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is not a defined for $x=4$, which means that it does not actually map into $\mathbb{R}$. So, this contradicts the well-definition of the function. This is not a well-defined function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.